# CIS RHEL shows "This is system is not registered with an entitlement server you can use subscription manager to register"

Tags: linux, azure, redhat, rhel7

Hey guys I purchased and deployed a CIS hardened image of RHELv 7.9 on my azure platform but now it shows the above message when I run the yum command to install or update something.

If I am not registered to an entitlement server does it make my instance illegal/pirated ?
If not then can I just disable my subscription manager plugin and I can use my instance without worrying much.

Comment: No, i am not taking advice on licensing , but just a query if someone has faced this before and what they have done to mitigate it. i have reached out to CIS as well.

Comment: You are asking about legality. That makes it a licensing question. Legal questions are better suited for [law.se].